# Android SDK - How can we detect the libraries or code in the app required to Google Play Service

Tags: android, google-play-services, huawei-mobile-services

I have a question need your help, I created an app and it's available on the Play Store, but when I installed it on Huawei's phone (without Google Play Service) the popup will show "This app won't run without Google Play Services which are missing from your phone". So how can I know what libraries or code in my app required to Google Play Services? Because I want to clone it to the new app and submit to Huawei AppGallery (without Google Play Services)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this IDE plug-in called [HMS Core Toolkit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/huawei-toolkit/) to help you analyze where GMS is used in your code.

Choose **HMS** > **Convertor** > **New Conversion** to start scanning, analysis, and conversion.

[The Convertor](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Tools-Guides/convertor-0000001050147221#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050147221__section7256151716342) is a code conversion tool supporting Java and Kotlin projects. This tool can help you quickly convert the existing Android app code for calling third-party APIs into the app code integrated with the HMS Core.

[New Conversion](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Tools-Guides/convertor-0000001050147221#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050147221__section63431841114315) can automatically convert the GMS APIs called by apps into HMS APIs, using either the To HMS API or Add HMS API conversion policy.

Comment: Thank you very much *shirley* I will check it

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do a conversions with HMS Toolkit but I always incur I issues, the project seems to miss always some classes.
Can you really convert project with it?

Comment: yes@Anchor,If an error message such as "Can't find...", "NoClassDefFoundError", "ClassNotFoundException", "NoSuchFieldException", or "NoSuchMethodException" is displayed after minifyEnabled is set to true, configure the following XMS obfuscation rules in app/proguard-rules.pro.For details,you can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68108809/13329100).