# HMS NoClassDefFoundError Android

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services

I'm using HMS plugin for Android Studio.

I have a class called `MyFirebaseMessagingService` which receives notifications from Firebase.

it used to be like :

```
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
...
}
```

after conversion:

```
import org.xms.f.messaging.ExtensionMessagingService;
import org.xms.f.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends ExtensionMessagingService {
...
}
```

After converting the code, I had the following problem :

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/xms/f/messaging/ExtensionMessagingService


 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.xms.f.messaging.ExtensionMessagingService" on path: DexPathList
```

**I found a suggested solution in Huawei support, but it didn't work!**

(Handle the exception)
link : https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Tools-Guides/map-conversion-0000001050062227

Suggested solution :

Add the following configuration to app/build.gradle:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled false
    }
}
```

btw I already clean and rebuild the project. Also, I tried to restart and invalidate.

**app/build.gradle. Before conversion:**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.marsa.store"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 24
        versionName "2.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.signing_configs
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    //ext lib
    // Retrofit & OkHttp
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    //side menu
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.4'
    //glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    //circle-img
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'


    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'

    implementation 'com.github.zcweng:switch-button:0.0.3@aar'


    // implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    //volley + gson
//    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'


    //finger + face recognition
    def biometric_version = '1.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.biometric:biometric:$biometric_version"


    //fcm
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-directboot:22.0.0'

    //country picker
    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.5.4'

}
```

**build.gradle (:xmsadapter),. After conversion:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.huawei.agconnect'
apply from: 'scripts/productFlavor.gradle'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }

}

dependencies {
    //Basement
    compileOnly 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0'
    compileOnly 'com.huawei.hms:base:6.0.1.302'
    compileOnly 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.1.0'
    compileOnly 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:17.0.0'
    //Push
    compileOnly 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
    compileOnly 'com.huawei.hms:push:5.3.0.304'
    compileOnly 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.0'
    compileOnly 'com.huawei.hms:hianalytics:6.1.0.300'
    compileOnly 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    //Map
    compileOnly 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    compileOnly 'com.huawei.hms:maps:5.3.0.300'
    compileOnly 'com.huawei.hms:location:6.0.0.302'
    compileOnly 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    compileOnly 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'
}
```

**stack trace :**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/xms/f/messaging/ExtensionMessagingService;
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1253)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3353)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.xms.f.messaging.ExtensionMessagingService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~A2nKXMdxonSKg_WgJRMT_Q==/com.marsa.store-vyoa6CNMY3Bwny01O9S41w==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~A2nKXMdxonSKg_WgJRMT_Q==/com.marsa.store-vyoa6CNMY3Bwny01O9S41w==/lib/x86, /data/app/~~A2nKXMdxonSKg_WgJRMT_Q==/com.marsa.store-vyoa6CNMY3Bwny01O9S41w==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95) 
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1253) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3353) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying almost everything I solved the problem. In order to help as many people as possible, I will write the steps you need to follow to get HMS map working :

1. **Create Huawei developer account**: https://id5.cloud.huawei.com/CAS/portal/userRegister/regbyemail.html
2. **Create a project and an app in Huawei Developer console, then get `agconnect-service.json` (After downloading make sure it is .json) file**:
   https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/cn/service/josp/agc/index.html#/

you can watch this video to help you:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BQbFlP4gRN8&t=1s

3. **Download and install HMS converter plugin from Android Market place**. The plugin will ask you to restart Android Studio.
4. **Before converting the project make sure to create a backup locally or on Github**.
5. **The following video will help you understand how to convert google APIs**.
   **Important note**: `@5:50 in the video the instructor will choose "To HMS API", You need to select "Add HMS API (GMS API First)"`.
   Also, `@6:53 in the video the instructor will click on automatic convert for all files. From a Personal Experience, it is better to convert files one by one manually.` **Actually, auto-convert is the cause of the issue I encountered**!
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1b1Ap5xQHm4&t=357s
6. **Make sure HMS converter added the following lines to your** `build:gradle/Project`:

   ```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
    ...

   // added by hms converter
   maven {url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/'}
   }

   dependencies {
    ...

    // added by hms converter
    classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-apms-plugin:1.4.1.305'
    classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.2.1.301'
     }
   }

   allprojects {
    repositories {
    ...

    // added by hms converter
    maven {url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/'}
     }
    }
   ```
7. **Make sure HMS converter added the following lines to your** `build:gradle/App`:

   ```
    android {
    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
     }
   }



    dependencies {
    // added by hms converter
    implementation project(':xmsadapter')
    implementation project(':xmsadapter:xmsaux')
    compileOnly project(':xmsadapter:xmsaux:xapi')

    ...

    //added by hms converter
    implementation 'com.huawei.hms:maps:5.3.0.300'
    implementation 'com.huawei.hms:location:6.0.0.302'


   }

   //added by hms converter
   apply plugin: 'com.huawei.agconnect'
   apply from: '../xmsadapter/scripts/productFlavor.gradle'
   ```
8. **Make sure HMS converter added the following lines to your** `Settings.gradle`:

   ```
   include ':app'
   ...
   // added by hms converter
   include ':xmsadapter', ':xmsadapter:xmsaux', ':xmsadapter:xmsaux:xg', ':xmsadapter:xmsaux:xh', ':xmsadapter:xmsaux:xapi'
   ```
9. **Add the following  rules to `proguard-rules.pro` in case minifyEnabled is true**:

   ```
       #<HMS Rules>
       -ignorewarnings
       -keepattributes *Annotation*
       -keepattributes Exceptions
       -keepattributes InnerClasses
       -keepattributes Signature
       -keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
       -keep class com.hianalytics.android.**{*;}
       -keep class com.huawei.updatesdk.**{*;}
       -keep class com.huawei.hms.**{*;}
       -keep class com.huawei.agconnect.**{*;}
       -keep interface com.huawei.agconnect.**{*;}
       -keep class com.huawei.hmf.**{*;}

       -keep class com.google.android.gms.**{*;}
       -keep interface com.google.android.gms.**{*;}

       -keep class com.google.firebase.**{*;}
       -keep interface com.google.firebase.**{*;}

       -keep class org.xms.**{*;}
       -keep interface org.xms.**{*;}

       #for map
       -keep class * extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment{*;}
       -keep class org.xms.g.maps.ExtensionMapOptions{*;}
       -keep class com.huawei.hms.maps.HuaweiMapOptions{*;}
       -keep class com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions{*;}
       -keep interface org.xms.g.maps.OnMapReadyCallback{*;}
       -keep interface com.huawei.hms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback{*;}
       -keep interface com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback{*;}
       -keep class org.xms.g.maps.StreetViewPanoramaOptions{*;}
       -keep class com.google.android.gms.maps.OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback{*;}
       -keep class com.huawei.hms.maps.OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback{*;}
       -keep interface org.xms.g.maps.OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback{*;}
       -keep interface com.google.android.gms.maps.OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback{*;}
       -keep interface com.huawei.hms.maps.OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback{*;}
       -keep class com.huawei.hms.dynamicloader.** { *; }
       -keep class com.huawei.hms.feature.dynamic.** {*;}
       -keep class com.huawei.hms.feature.** { *;}



       #</HMS Rules>
   ```
10. **Clean then Rebuild the project, you may need to "restart and invalidate" Android studio**.
11. **you can check this github project as a reference**: https://github.com/AlineJo/AdapterMap

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Tools-Guides/faq-0000001050061059#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050061059__section1648654845516):

If an error message such as **"Can't find..."**, **"NoClassDefFoundError"**, **"ClassNotFoundException"**, **"NoSuchFieldException"**, or **"NoSuchMethodException"** is displayed after **minifyEnabled** is set to **true**, configure the following XMS obfuscation rules in **app/proguard-rules.pro**:

```
-ignorewarnings
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keepattributes InnerClasses
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep class com.hianalytics.android.**{*;}
-keep class com.huawei.updatesdk.**{*;}
-keep class com.huawei.hms.**{*;}
-keep class com.huawei.agconnect.**{*;}
-keep interface com.huawei.agconnect.**{*;}
-keep class com.huawei.hmf.**{*;}

-keep class com.google.android.gms.**{*;}
-keep interface com.google.android.gms.**{*;}

-keep class com.google.firebase.**{*;}
-keep interface com.google.firebase.**{*;}

-keep class org.xms.**{*;}
-keep interface org.xms.**{*;}
```

Comment: thanks for sharing, will try it and will give feedback

Comment: Sure.Should you need help with anything else, please feel free to reach out back to us.

Comment: so sorry to take long time to replay. I was just accepted as Huawei dev.

anyways, even after this code to my app/proguard-rules.pro, still i get same problem!

Comment: hi@Joseph Ali, Could you provide us the app/build.gradle and /xms/adapter/build.gradle, both before and after convorted are need. Thanks. Maybe the version is not suit to Convorter Plugin.

Comment: hi@Joseph Ali, We check the build.gradle files before and after converted. The version in your build.gradle is OK. And the convert is successfully! So we think maybe the reason is the xmsadpter module is building failed.

Comment: The solution is to configure your project following the 'Configuring the ClassLoader' part,  of which the url is https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Tools-Guides/push-conversion-0000001050060304#section1180193318535, and rescan again.

Comment: problem solved, everything was correct! but for some reason, if I clicked on the "automatic convert for all files button" android will prompt the same error. I simply restore the backup, then start over again, but this time I manually clicked on each API and convert it and It worked! for now at least. Super thanks to you.